# Why can all invertible matrices be row reduced to the identity matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

All my textbook has covered so far is this:

[image]

But then the textbook hits me with this:

[image]

which basically tells me that an invertible matrix can be row reduced to I (multiplying on the left by elementary matrices I just learned is equivalent to a series of row operations). Why is this? I don't really find this intuitive.

Comment: Which book did you take the excerpt from?

Comment: Have you looked at all the questions stackexchange lists in the margin as Related? This one might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1997523/why-can-the-row-reduced-echelon-matrix-r-only-be-identity-matrix?rq=1

Comment: Elementary Linear Algebra by Larson 7th edition @PtF

Comment: Thanks @Jwan622

Comment: Thoughts? Do you have a clarification?

Comment: Can you try to rephrase your question? I tried two guess it twice but you commented that I did not get it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which basics of linear algebra you've covered so far, it should be straightforward to check that:

- A matrix is invertible if and only if its row reduced echelon form is invertible
- A matrix in row reduced echelon form is invertible if and only if it is the identity matrix

Answer (score 1):

> which basically tells me that an invertible matrix can be row reduced
>   to I (multiplying on the left by elementary matrices I just learned is
>   equivalent to a series of row operations). Why is this? I don't really
>   find this intuitive.

Is it unclear thar row operations can be expressed by multiplication with a elementary matrix?

You should have a look of the elementary matrices and check for yourself, that multiplication with them gives the same result as a row operation would.

$$
E A = A'
$$

So if $E$ is the elementary matrix for swapping certain two rows then $A'$ should be the same as $A$ having those two rows swapped.

Or is it unclear why $A$ can be expressed as a product of the inverses  of elementary matrices (acting on $I$)? Or equivalent: $A^{-1}$ can be expressed as product of elementary matrices.

This is because the Gauss elimination procedure is basically acting like a multiplication with an inverse. And this can be expressed as product of elementary matrices.

Comment: The question was why an invertible matrix can be row reduced to the identity matrix, not why row operations can be described by matrices.

Comment: Yeah this answer while okay doesn't get at my question

Comment: @md2perpe See the last two paragraphs