# A square matrix in the reduced row echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I'm reading the Introduction to Abstract Algebra by W. Keith Nicholson. In the matrix inverses section for the proving many properties, implicitly it has been used the following statement:

> If a square matrix is in the reduced row echelon form, it is either
>   identity matrix or has a zero row.

I really have no idea about the proof and also searching wasn't useful.

Comment: This follows directly from the definition of reduced row echelon form.

Comment: @amd Can you explain please ? It's really difficult for me to see that comes from the definition.

Comment: Count the number of "leading ones" if it's not the identity matrix.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Can you give an example? Unfortunately, I'm unable to understand your solution.

Comment: $\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&1\cr}$ has two leading ones. $\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&0\cr}$ and $\pmatrix{0&1\cr0&0\cr}$ each have only one leading one.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Okay and how it shows a zero row ?

Comment: Think about it. Suppose an $n\times n$ matrix in reduced row-echelon form has $n$ leading ones. What must the matrix be? Now, suppose it has fewer than $n$ leading ones. Can every row have a leading one?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I don't know whether there is a formal proof or not.

Comment: Of course there is a formal proof. Why wouldn't there be one?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I tried to find that but I couldn't find it. Could you post that as an answer please?

Comment: Can you find an informal proof? That's a good starting point for getting a formal proof.

Comment: @GerryMyerson According to the amd's comment, It can easily be proved using the definition of rref but I don't know how.

Comment: You claim to know the definition, but I'm not convinced. If you know the definition, and you've thought about what we've worked out in the comments, then you ought to be able to put together *some* kind of proof. If you can't do that, then please show me that you understand the definition of reduced row-echelon form.

Comment: Let me put it another way: pick some $n$, and try to write down an $n\times n$ matrix, in reduced row-echelon form, not the identity matrix, and not having a zero row, and think about why it turns out to be so hard to do it. Then put that in words.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Okay , If we consider an $n\times n$ matrix then if the last row is zero we're done . Otherwise, in the last row we should have a nonzero entry. What's the next step?

Comment: OK, so, where in the last row can that nonzero entry be?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Finally, I understand that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Good. If you understand, let me encourage you to write it up, and post it as an answer.

Comment: Today would be a good day to do that, S.H.W.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think this answer did the job very well: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1997523/why-can-the-row-reduced-echelon-matrix-r-only-be-identity-matrix