# Elementary proof of: $R$ in RREF is invertible if and only if $R=I$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am reading through Hoffman and Kunze and they mention that "since $R$ is a (square) row-reduced echelon matrix, $R$ is invertible if and only if $R=I$."

One implication is obvious. I am having trouble for some reason proving that if $R$ is in RREF and invertible, then it must be the identity matrix. The proof is introduced very early in the text where stuff like rank, nullity, row space etc. have not been mentioned yet. Is there a more "elementary" proof of this fact? I know this seems super basic but it's been bugging me.

Comment: Does [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1997523/why-can-the-row-reduced-echelon-matrix-r-only-be-identity-matrix?rq=1) answer your question? It seems to be referring to the exact same question.

Comment: The previous comment should indeed answer you question, but informally speaking: it because of the demand of being in row reduced echelon form is really really strong. Look at the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\  0 & 4 & 5 \\ 0 & 0 & 6 \end{pmatrix}$ which I obtained with a lot of patient and hard work from a different matrix with no zeroes in it. In any sensible universe I would be allowed to stop here with my reductions: the matrix is in echelon form and I can easily see whether or not it is invertible (yes, in this case). However for the RREF people this is not enough (ct in next cmt)

Comment: So I grab my faithful pencil and go on with reducing, multplying, substracting, until I finally, tongue on my shoes, arrive at $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 6 \end{pmatrix}$. Ok but now I am certainly allowed to go to sleep am I? If there ever was any doubt about the matrix being invertible it is cleared up now, right? But nooooo.... In order to earn the title RREF I must reduce further, divide the second row by 4 and the third by 6. Well, yeah, if the demands for being in RREF are that high then obviously I am gonna end up with something is or looks very close to id

Comment: In other words: you can pretty much write down the very small hand full of square matrices that are allowed to call themselves RREF and check which ones of them are invertible.