# An Invertible n by n matrix can be reduced to the identity matrix using elementary row operations - A proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm quite new to Linear Algebra and just wondered if someone could take me through the proof above? I realise some people have asked this before but I'm afraid some parts weren't understandable for me. I have learnt row reduced echelon forms and etc but just can't piece a proof together. Thank you very much!

As Ben suggested, this is the one I've seen -

[Why can the row-reduced echelon matrix $R$ only be identity matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1997523/why-can-the-row-reduced-echelon-matrix-r-only-be-identity-matrix?rq=1)

Upon closer inspection, it's actually answered by you Ben!

So essentially, the bit I couldn't understand was why can't the RREF have a single row full of zeros? And what makes having a RREF matrix with a row full of zeros not invertible?

Apologies if I'm missing something very obvious :)

Comment: Rather than asking us to write a complete proof and hoping that it explains whatever ideas you had trouble understanding, it would be better if you could link us to or summarize one of the proofs that you found and explain exactly which parts weren't understandable.

Comment: I have edited my post above @BenGrossmann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why can't the RREF have a single row full of zeros? And what makes having a RREF matrix with a row full of zeros not invertible?

Answering the second question addresses the first, so let's start there. Suppose that $R$ is an $n \times n$ matrix whose last row is zero. It follows that for any vector $x \in \Bbb R^n$, the vector $Rx$ will have a zero as its last entry; I recommend that you try to convince yourself that this is true using the definition of matrix multiplication.

With the above observation, we see that the equation $Rx = b$ where
$$
b = \pmatrix{0\\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ 1}
$$
cannot have a solution. However, if $R$ were invertible, then the equation *would* have a solution because
$$
Rx = b \iff 
R^{-1}Rx = R^{-1}b \iff x = R^{-1}b.
$$
So because $R$ has a final row of zeros, the equation $Rx = b$ does not have a solution, which implies that $R$ is not invertible.

Comment: I see - thank you for the clear explanation @BenGrossmann ! I just want to double check the overall thinking if that's ok with you. So, because of the above, R cannot have a zero row anywhere. This means that all rows have pivots and because R is RREF, the pivots are all going to be 1. Then given the nature of RREF and n pivots in a n by n matrix, we have that the pivots must go exactly in the positions that would make R equal to the identity matrix. Would this reasoning be correct?

Comment: @pog_ant Yes, that's correct